# Fireplace (vim plugin) needs python support

Tags: python, windows, vim, clojure

So, I've installed the Fireplace plugin, but there's a python dependency:

```
The only external dependency is that you have either a Vim with Python support compiled in, or python in your path.
```

I've tried to install first Python3 and then Python2.7, with also 'python' in the path.
However, it's still not working, and even after reinstalling vim while having both Python versions in my system, if I type

```
echo has('python')
```

in vim the answer is 0.

How on earth can I make vim recognize Python?
Also, when I type :help python-dynamic in vim, it says that vim wants python 2.4 instead of 2.7... is this vim's or fireplace's fault?
There are no binary installers for 2.4, and compiling python from source in windows is a living nightmare..

EDIT: After restarting the computer with Python 2.7 installed, instead of saying

```
Python interface not working
```

Vim instantly crashes.

EDIT: I've found the solution:
In addition to having Vim built with Python support, it seems it is necessary, for some reason, to install Python 2.7.9 instead of the latest build of Python 2.
Hope this can help some people.

Comment: `has('python')` will only tell you if Python support is compiled in.

Comment: @DanielRoseman This means that having python support is unrelated to having python actually compiled, correct? But since I can have either python support in vim or 'python' in my path, I don't understand why installing python while having no vim support doesn't make the plugin work..

Comment: Please forgive my confusion, but what relation does this question have with Clojure?

Comment: @NathanDavis The Fireplace plugin makes a connection between vim and the Clojure REPL; I added that tag since people coding in clojure might also work with that plugin and know the problem

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I knew I was missing something.  I see now that Fireplace must be implemented (at least in part) in Python.